# Convert copied content to lowercase in excel

Tags: excel, lowercase

I have two different excel sheets. Data in one sheet is in uppercase. I want to copy that data in another sheet, but in lowercase. Up till now I used to copy the uppercase data, paste it in a column(not desired) of the other sheet and use the formula =LOWER() and copy it to the desired column. Is there a way I could convert the data into lowercase on the fly, without having to copy to another column, converting it and pasting it in the desired column. That would save a lot of time.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the sheet you want to copy it put `=LOWER(Tabelle2!A1:A12)`. Just write `=LOWER(` and select the area from the other sheet.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a native method of bulk case conversion in Excel but you can reduce the amount of work by identifying the cells that need conversion. Here is a quick macro that copied the `ActiveSheet` to the end of the worksheet queue and runs through all text-based cells to convert then to strictly lower case.

```
Sub dupe_as_lower()
    Dim rCNVRT As Range
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    For Each rCNVRT In Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        rCNVRT = LCase(rCNVRT.Value)
    Next rCNVRT
End Sub
```

If the `xlTextValues` parameter is too restrictive, post back with some more detail and adjustments could be offered.